# Content Structure in Bolt CMS

Tags: bolt-cms

I am working on building a site using Bolt CMS (excellent tool, thanks Bolt developers).  I would like build the site so that it is four layers deep like so:

www.example.com/categoryA/subcategoryA1/topicA1

www.example.com/categoryB/subcategoryB1/topicB1

www.example.com/categoryC/subcategoryC1/topicC1

I have been looking at various combinations of contenttypes and taxonomies, but have not come up with a combination that will provide a site structure as described.  Seeking advice.

Comment: I would think that you could use `routing.yml` to map these out, but that isn't the best option. Unfortunately, as the feature has not been implemented as yet, hierarchies are not very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing that with taxonomies is hard, but have you considered using the menu.yml to show those categories? Then it's a piece of cake.

You may choose to use the MenuEditor extension if you want to let your editors drag and drop things.